# Parse ffmpeg output into batch variable

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

help please.
I am on Windows command line and I want ffmpeg error returned as variable.
Tried many things, still not working.

```
@echo off&setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
SET S="path\to\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -i InputFile.FLV -vframes 1 -an -s 400x222 -ss 30 OutputFile.jpg
!S!
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ('!S!') do set var=%%A
echo !var!
```

The result is that the statement !S! produces the correct output on the console (`InputFile.FLV: No such file or directory`) but does not put that into the variable. The output of echo !var! statement simply shows as `"path\to\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -i InputFile.FLV -vframes 1 -an -s 400x222 -ss 30 OutputFile.jpg`

How do I get the output of !S! into !var!?

Comment: Try to add `2^>^&1` to `!S!`; since the output seems to be an error message, it might be returned at stream _STDERR_ (handle `2`), but `for /F` only captures _STDOUT_ (handle `1`), therefore you may need to redirect _STDERR_ to _STDOUT_ (escaped by `^` since the command line is executed by `for /F`)...

Comment: @Compo: Yes adding `2>&1` was part of the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` explicitly disables delayed expansion and so `!S!` is not expanded delayed at all. For that reason the command line with just `!S!` results in an error message on execution of the batch file and definitely not in output `InputFile.FLV: No such file or directory`. And last line just outputs the string `!var!`.

The usage of `for` option `usebackq` results in interpreting the string between `'`...`'` as **string** and not as command line to execute with `%ComSpec% /c` in a background command process. For that reason the **string** `!S!` is assigned to variable `var`.

Therefore it can be expected that batch file was executed with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in real to get the outputs as written in question.

This not tested batch file should work for this task.

```
@echo off
set "var="
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('""path\to\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -i InputFile.FLV -vframes 1 -an -s 400x222 -ss 30 OutputFile.jpg 2>&1"') do set "var=%%I"
if defined var set var
```

Command **FOR** with option `/F` without using option `usebackq` and with a command line defined between the two `'` executes in background `%ComSpec% /c` and the string between the two `'` appended. So executed with Windows being installed in `C:\Windows` is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""path\to\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -i InputFile.FLV -vframes 1 -an -s 400x222 -ss 30 OutputFile.jpg 2>&1"
```

The started Windows command processor instanced running in background removes in this case first and last `"` before executing the remaining command line:

```
"path\to\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -i InputFile.FLV -vframes 1 -an -s 400x222 -ss 30 OutputFile.jpg 2>&1
```

`ffmpeg.exe` not installed by me at all outputs information like this one as far as I know to handle **STDERR** (standard error) instead of **STDOUT** (standard output). But **FOR** captures just output written to handle **STDOUT** of started command process. For that reason `2>&1` is needed to redirect output written to handle **STDERR** of background command process by `ffmpeg.exe` to handle **STDOUT** of background command process for being also captured by **FOR** of command process which is processing the batch file.

With **FOR** options argument string `delims^=^ eol^=` an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character is defined to really get always the entire line as captured by **FOR** assigned to specified loop variable `I`. The two options are specified here by way of an exception not enclosed in `"` as otherwise it is not possible to define an empty list of delimiters **and** no end of line character. The two equal signs and the space must be escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal characters and not as argument string separators because of not being enclosed in a double quoted argument string.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?` ... explains how double quotes in string(s) after option `/C` or `/K` are interpreted by Windows command processor and when a file name (or any other argument string) must be enclosed in `"` on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|> ``.
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Great answer and helped me a lot. Of course it was set to enabledelayedexpansion I mixed that up from the wrong file. But `delims^=^ eol^= ` was brilliant and is doing exactly what I was hoping for.